# Execute LIWC program with input text file outputing text file on OS X

Tags: macos, unix, nlp

I am new to UNIX and would like to execute an external program from the command line.  The program is [LIWC](http://liwc.net/) and it is one which I bought.

It processes a text from a text file (input) and outputs the result to a text file.

The codes that I am running have the same flaw: they hang while generating an empty text output file.

These are some codes that I have tried:

```
/path/file.exe < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

and

```
infile.txt | /path/file.exe > outfile.txt
```

With this last code, there is an initial reading of infile.txt line by line with a final

```
<syntax error: unexpected end of file>
```

I appreciate any orientation!

EDIT

Unfortunately this is the answer from supplier:

> There is no command line interface for the Mac nor Windows version of
>   LIWC2007

Comment: There is little we can do without the code.  The first should work if, when you type the program's name with no I/O redirection, you can type data at the terminal and see the results on the screen.  The second won't work ever (unless for some weird reason `input.txt` is actually an executable (script) file; you might be thinking of `cat input.txt | /path/file.exe > outfile.txt`.  What error message(s), if any, are you getting?

Comment: Does your program use stdin for input or does it expect to be given a file name ? Ditto for stdout and the output file name ?

Comment: Does `infile.txt | /path/file.exe` without the output file displays something ?

Comment: No, because `infile.txt` is not executable; you need `cat infile.txt | ...`.

Comment: @PaulR, when I run the program "manually" it expects me to provide a txt file as input. Same for output. After I provide these two files it processes the text to the output file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, when testing for `cat input.txt | /path/file.exe > outfile.txt` I am not getting any error message.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I do not have the code. It is a soft that I purchased.

Comment: The final error message indicates that the input isn't in the format expected by your program.  You'll need to find the manual for the software (program) and find out what is expected as input.  There is nothing at all that we can do to help you unless you identify the program (name, URL) and show your sample input (or, at least, some sample input that generates the same error).

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler. The program is LIWC and the url is http://www.liwc.net/. I will find out what is expected as input (when ran manually it is a text file).

Comment: Please include such information in an edit to the question in future (or in the original question).  I've done that for you this time, though you're welcome to do a better job (for example, instead of adding the comment at the end and in the title, include the name and URL information up front).

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler !!! Lesson learned.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I posted the supplier's answer (EDIT). Thanks for the support!